# Replacing values in a table with values in a look up table

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have data stored in a table that requires specific values to be removed so it can be shared more widely.
The data that needs to be removed will have a key as below:

Data Table

| Statement | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| First Name | Mike |
| Last Name | Smith |
| Position | Fitter |
| Country | France |
| Years Worked | 25 |

Look up

| Key | Return |
| --- | --- |
| First Name | Redacted |
| Last Name | Removed |
| Country | Not Available |

Output:

| Statement | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| First Name | Redacted |
| Last Name | Removed |
| Position | Fitter |
| Country | Not Available |
| Years Worked | 25 |

I tried using a join and I tried using SET to match the columns when Statement = Key. Both of these I managed to replace the values in the Answer column with values in Return but it also replaced the values that didn't have a match in the look up column with NULL

---

Code I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Data Table] DATA
LEFT JOIN [Lookup up] DSL
ON DATA.[Statement] = DSL.[Key]
```

and

```
UPDATE [Data Table Sanitised]
SET [Answer] = (
SELECT [Return]
FROM [Look up]
WHERE [Key] = [Statement]
)
```

Both returned:

| Statement | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| First Name | Redacted |
| Last Name | Removed |
| Position | NULL |
| Country | Not Available |
| Years Worked | NULL |

Comment: you should use `ISNULL([Return], [Answer])` so if lookup is not available, the original data is returned

Comment: if you do the update, the ISNULL should be around your whole subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example data:

```
create table #data
(
    [Statement] varchar(20),
    Answer varchar(10)
)

insert into #data values
('First Name','Mike'),
('Last Name','Smith'),
('Position','Fitter'),
('Country','France'),
('Years Worked','25')

create table #lookup
(
    [Key] varchar(20),
    [Return] varchar(20)
)

insert into #lookup values
('First Name','Redacted'),
('Last Name','Removed'),
('Country','Not Available')
```

This gives the expected output:

```
select
    d.[Statement],
    coalesce(l.[Return],d.Answer) as Answer
from #data d
left join #lookup l on d.[Statement] = l.[Key]
```

Result:

| Statement | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| First Name | Redacted |
| Last Name | Removed |
| Position | Fitter |
| Country | Not Available |
| Years Worked | 25 |

Comment: Excellent thank you, that works great. I will have to do some swatting up on coalesce as its not a statement I have used before in SQL.

Comment: You're very welcome and thanks for accepting my answer - if you found the answer helpful, please consider upvoting as well. [`COALESCE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) is a handy function when you have multiple values and want to return the first non-NULL one. For two values, it works essentially the same as [`ISNULL()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql).

Comment: My apologies @DaleK, I didn't realise this was not allowed. Thanks for letting me know.